# Typo3 getting data and convert it to specific xml schema

Tags: php, mysql, xml, typo3

i am new to typo3, so sorry, if this is too obvious.
I do not expect a complete solution, just the topics i would need to read about in order to solve the task would be perfectly enough. :)

Here the task:
I have a typo 3 installation with job advertisements in it. Now the company wants to publish that data in to a social website, which needs to have the job advertisement data put on a server in an xml feed, which looks like this: http://www.kununu.com/docs#jobfeed. Don't worry about what it says in there, it's just stuff like Job Title, Description etc.

Like i said, i am completely new to this and just have a vague idea.

My thoughts so far were something like this:

- I probably need to write a plugin, which pulls the data out of typo3 by the push of a button
- That Plugin need to establish a database connection to pull the data (probably it's mysql, but i am not entirely sure yet)
- The data need to be formatted, which is either done by some string operations or by some kind of xml handler i assume.
- Sidenote: I read something about TypoScript, but i'd like to avoid that, since it's a one time project and probably not worth the time to learn it. For me at least.

Thank you loads for your help in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Your plan sounds sane. You could start with a PHP script first that lays next to the typo3 installment so that you don't need to write a full plugin, just a script that fetches data from the database. You then can execute that script every night (or every hour) via cron as well. Then nobody needs to push any button.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to do it with a separate script. That stuff could break when updating, since the database schema could change. If the job advertisements are done with an extension, the main question is how the extension is build - the "old" way (pibase) or with extbase (MVC). If the latter one, you can just add another template for XML, and print that out on a separate page type (which needs some typoscript, though).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the late reply. Definitely helped to get me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle that (basicly with typoscript). The other part has to come from PHP (F.e. extbase plugin) ... First part creates the XML output. Second part uses my Demo plugin to include data (Pages+special fields) from DB.

Within TS we are able to create a new typeNum. With that you can call your XML. ( ?type=1234 ) Within the BE you can select each page for output.

If you need help just contact me. I would send you the plugin.

```
sitemap = PAGE
sitemap {
  typeNum = 1234

   config {
    # Set charset to utf-8
    metaCharset = utf-8
    # Deactivate TYPO3 Header Code
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    # Content-type settings
    additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
    # Do not cache the page
    no_cache = 1
    # No xhtml cleaning trough TYPO3
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
  }


  10 = USER_INT
  10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        pluginName = Sitemap
        extensionName = Srcxmlprovider
        controller = Sitemap
        vendorName = Sourcecrew
        action = exportXml
        switchableControllerActions {
          Sitemap {
            1 = exportXml
          }
        }
  }


}
```

Ich habe die EXT noch schnell ins TER gepushed. Ein Tutorial liegt innerhalb.

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/srcxmlprovider

Comment: That was extremly helpful! Thanks a lot for that! Defintely going to contact you, if i have further questions! Dankeschön für das Angebot ;)